# shell while read command execution

Tags: bash

Please help me to find out this problem solution

```
 #!bin/bash 
 while read line; do

  if [[ $line =~ "some thing match on line"]] ; then
    echo  "---->   $line"
    NAME=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"=" -f2)
    PATH=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d"=" -f2)  
  fi
done < "pattern.xml"
#output
##line 6: awk: command not found
##line 6: cut: command not found
```

why this command not execute inside while loop 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `PATH` environment variable here:

```
PATH=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d"=" -f2)
```

That variable is the search path used to find programs. So after the first iteration of the loop, you won't be able to find programs, because it no longer contains directories like `/usr/bin`.

Use a different variable name. And in general, avoid using all uppercase variables in your scripts, as this is conventionally reserved for environment variables.